# How to combine two pandas series?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, series

I have a dataframe which looks like this

```
        Date           Description Deposits Withdrawls Balance
0       21-Aug-2020    Cash        0.00     10612.14   53063.19
...     ...            ...         ...      ...        ...
1000000 15-Nov-2155    Cheque      0.00     12345.00   55511.00
```

After performing this two operations

```
res1 = df.groupby('Date')['Withdrawls'].mean()
res2 = df.groupby(['Date', 'Description'])['Withdrawls'].mean()
```

I get two Series which look like this:

```
print(res1)
Date
2020-08-21  77189.019273
...
2155-11-15  125627.741943
Name: Withdrawls, Length: 49394, dtype: float64
```

and this:

```
print(res2)
Date       Description
2020-08-21 ATM          76862.370556
           Bill         44174.444545
           ...          ...
2155-11-15 Purchase     95530.093750
           RTGS         306642.666000
           ...          ...
Name: Withdrawls, Length: 650468, dtype: float64
```

What I need is to combine them like this. The empty description is a result from `res1` and others are results from `res2`. How do I do it? (Assume that we also have series which get min and max for each grouping like `res1` and `res2`. For simplicity you can just assume there is no Min and Max columns)

```
        Date           Type                          Min      Max        Avg
0       21-Aug-2020    Description="Reversal"        0.00     10612.14   53063.19
...     ...            ...                           ...      ...        ...
1000000 15-Nov-2155                                  0.00     12345.00   55511.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create 2 DataFrames `df11, df22` first, add column `Description`, join together and sorting per multiple columns:

```
print (df)
                Date Description  Deposits  Withdrawls   Balance
0        21-Aug-2020        Cash       0.0        10.0  53063.19
0        21-Aug-2020        Cash       0.0       114.0  53063.19
0        21-Aug-2020        Cash       0.0       107.0  53063.19
1000000  15-Nov-2155      Cheque       0.0     12345.0  55511.00

df11 = (df.groupby(['Date', 'Description'])['Withdrawls']
          .agg(['min','max','mean'])
          .reset_index())

df22 = df.groupby('Date')['Withdrawls'].agg(['min','max','mean']).reset_index()

df = (pd.concat([df11, df22.reindex(df11.columns, fill_value='', axis=1)])
        .sort_values(['Date','Description'], ascending=[True, False], ignore_index=True))
print (df)
          Date Description      min      max     mean
0  15-Nov-2155      Cheque  12345.0  12345.0  12345.0
1  15-Nov-2155              12345.0  12345.0  12345.0
2  21-Aug-2020        Cash     10.0    114.0     77.0
3  21-Aug-2020                 10.0    114.0     77.0
```

Comment: Yes, you did understand me right. the final dataframe is giving me KeyError. Says it needs to rewrap columns in Series to apply key function when sort_values() is called.

Comment: @Asekeeewka - Can you test `df22.reindex(df11.columns, fill_value='', axis=1)` instead `assign` ?

Comment: same error. KeyError: 'Date'. Forgot to mention it above.

Comment: @Asekeeewka - I use `reset_index` instaed `as_index=False`, can you test now?